# Where can I find some beginner tutorials that use Version 3.1?

Tags: modeling

I am interest in learning Blender as a replacement for TinkerCad for 3D printer project modelling.  I have tried any number of beginner tutorials, but they all use an earlier version of Blender, with radically different user interface layouts.  It is very frustrating to have to search through minutia in the help files for 3.1, just to find that the function described in the tutorial that has been moved to an entirely different area.

Any help would be appreciated

TIA,

Frank

Comment: If its not related to geometry nodes, 2.80 tutorial would be helpful too

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Blender Guru's donut tutorials? They're kind of a meme in the community at this point but I think they're a pretty helpful way to get your foot in the door.

[Blender 3.0 Beginner Tutorial - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw)

[Blender 2.8 Beginner Tutorial - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4)